# Change constraint on column based on value of another

Tags: postgresql, constraint, condition, check-constraints

Is it possible to change a constraint on a column in postgres based on the value of another column?
E.g. (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    type TXN_TYPE NOT NULL,
    amount BIGINT,
    . . . .,
    refunded boolean DEFAULT FALSE,
    refund_id DEFAULT NULL if (CONSTRAINT link_refund CHECK (refunded=TRUE))=TRUE REFERENCES transactions(id)
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A foreign key can not be "conditional". The only "exception" to that rule are `null` values which can't reference another table by definition.

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to implement a constraint that says "if refunded is `true` then `refund_id` must reference an existing transaction".

I don't think you need the `refunded` column at all. Because the flag `refunded` can be derived from the value of the `refund_id`  using the expression: `refund_id is not null`.

If you do want a column like that, just create a view with that expression.

If you do insist on having the redundant `refunded` flag, you could setup a check constraint like this:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    type TXN_TYPE NOT NULL,
    amount BIGINT,
    . . . .,
    refunded boolean DEFAULT FALSE,
    refund_id integer null REFERENCES transactions,
    constraint check_refund 
       check ( (refunded and refund_id is not null or
               (not refunded and refund_id is null) ) 
);
```

Comment: Why can one be certain that it is redundant? Also a `refund_id integer NULL REFERENCES transactions` by itself will default to null AND constrain values to transactions(id), correct?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull: why it is redundant? Well if `refunded` is true, apparently `refund_id` must be not null and therefor it points to a valid transaction. If `refunded` is false, `refund_id` should be `null`. Unless the last assumption is not correct, the value of `refunded` can be deduced by the fact that a `refund_id` exists. And yes, that's how foreign keys work.

Comment: it's clear to me why it could be redundant, not that it definitely is. I get the drift though :)

Comment: If you allow `refunded = true AND refund_id IS NULL` then (and only then) it would not be redundant. But that would seem like a strange combination to allow.